# C# Docker - Network Share

Tags: c#, docker, docker-volume

I have a C# ASP.NET MVC solution (full .NET framework) currently hosted under IIS.  It is similar to an image library. Photos are stored on a network share and are served up to the web solution using UNC paths.

I am trying to containerise the solution and I have managed to get the application running in Docker on windows container (Server 2016), but I am not sure how to get the UNC network share working.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you "mount" that share onto a known internal path?

Comment: @HansKeﬆing I am not sure.  My docker skills are quite light on volumes and mounts.  The server is a windows server connected to a SAN device for storage.  It is not mapped as a drive but is accessible using UNC paths